# como pegar um elemento Pai a partir de um filho com id?

Tags: javascript, html, css

tenho o seguinte codigo:

```
<div></div>

<div>
  <div class='minhaClasse'>
    <div id='text'>hhaushdus</div>
    <input name='profile_id' />
  <div>
</div>
```

Preciso pegar essa `div`:

```
<div class='minhaClasse'>
  <div id='text'>hhaushdus</div>
  <input name='profile_id' />
<div>
```

Tentei desta maneira:

```
let element = document.getElementsByName('profile_id')[0].parentNode;
```

isso me retornou o pai:

```
<div>
  <div class='minhaClasse'>
    <div id='text'>hhaushdus</div>
    <input name='profile_id' />
  <div>
</div>
```

Basicamente são duas perguntas, como eu pego esta `div` com a classe **'minhaClasse'** e se tem como fazer um `getElement` de um `getElement` tipo:

```
document.getElementsByName('profile_id')[0].parentNode.getElementByClassName('minhaClasse'));
```

Comment: Mas o objetivo é apanhar um elemento pai com a classe `minhaClasse` ou um irmão ? No exemplo dado `minhaClasse` é pai de `profile_id`

Answer (score 1):

Eu recomendo dar uma olhada em https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_childnodes.asp
Não lembro qual a sintaxe correta mas acho que esse código especifico pode te ajudar https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_node_childnodes2

## EDIT

Esqueci de por alguns detalhes para referenciar um div especifico vc deve mostrar pro código qual div vc quer, recomendo colocar um id na div pai e dps executar os comandos e códigos que vc quer,

Exemplo:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var c = document.getElementById("myDIV").childNodes;
    c[1].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}
```

```html
<div></div>

<div id="myDIV">PAI
  <div class='minhaClasse'>FILHO
    <div id='text'>hhaushdus</div>
    <input name='profile_id' />
  <div>
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: Eu só queria entender pq dão negativo se estou tentando ajudar ... E se a resposta não está errada por si só

Comment: Recomendo não colocar o link do artigo, em vez disso, transcreva-o.

Comment: Eu editei dando um exemplo... Mas agora vou realmente escrever e colocar fontes

Answer (score 1):

você pode fazer o seguinte:

`x = document.getElementsByClassName("minhaClasse");`

isto vai retornar todos os elementos que possuem esta classe, depois basta você iterar e realizar o processo que você deseja:

```
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    //seu código aqui
}
```