# Adicionar ID sequencial nas DIV para depois ocultar

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho que manipular alguns campos sem ter acesso ao `form`.

Quando estou ocultando os campos input, está fincando as linhas da `div`, fazendo com que `form` fique com buracos entre as linhas.

Minha ideia seria adicionar id sequencial nessas `div`s para depois ocultar.

Caso tenha alguma outra sugestão, será muito bem vinda.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Hoje estou aplicando `setAttribute` e `style` tudo através do `window.onload`:

```
window.onload = function(){
      document.getElementById('rd-text_field-kkzqscvf').onblur = function(){validarCPF(this);}
      document.getElementById('rd-text_field-kkzqscvj').setAttribute("maxlength", "10");
      document.getElementById('rd-number_field-kkzqscvp').style.visibility = "hidden"
etc...
   }
```

Answer (score -2):

Até onde consigo entender, você pretende esconder as divs que são pais de elementos inputs e gostaria que quando um input fosse oculto a div também fosse.

Partindo desse pressuposto, considere colocar id nas divs ao invés do input em si, mesmo por que atráves da div você pode acessar o input sendo o mesmo, filho da div.

Você também pode fazer o inverso, pegando o pai do input que tem o id. Considere ver essa questão que está no **stack overflow**: [como pegar um elemento Pai a partir de um filho com id?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/335952/como-pegar-um-elemento-pai-a-partir-de-um-filho-com-id)

A partir disso creio que possa ser resolvido seu problema. Espero ter ajudado! :D

Comment: Olá Matheus, valeu pelo feedback.

Na verdade preciso colocar ID na DIV, pq o form tem várias DIV todas com a mesma class mas nenhuma delas tem ID.

Estou verificando como resolver com essa sua sugestão no stack overflow.

Comment: Consegui fazer através da sua dica.
Preciso agora adaptar para chamar essa function no momento que carregar o formulário.
document.getElementById('rd-number_field-kkzh10aq').onkeypress = function(){this.parentElement.style.display = 'none';};

Comment: Creio que em um arquivo javascript vanilla consiga carregar uma função na criação do DOM você poderia fazer da seguinte forma: 
`myFunction()


document.getElementById('rd-number_field-kkzh10aq').onkeypress = myFunction()


myFunction() {this.parentElement.style.display = 'none';}`

Comment: Consegui esse:

var item = document.getElementById("rd-number_field-kkzh10aq");

function removeLi() {
  item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
}

Comment: [ Resolvido ]
Adicionei

.parentElement.style.display = 'none';

document.getElementById('id').parentElement.style.display = 'none';